# How to pick the "correct" solution from a system of polynomial equations?

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

I have a system of equations of the form
$$
\begin{aligned}
a &=z+\frac{x}{y^2} &(1)\\
b &=x-2c\frac{x}{y}+ac^2 &(2)\\
c &=y-\frac{z}{x}y^3 &(3),
\end{aligned}
$$
where $a>0$, $b\geq 0$, and $c>0$.  The solution $(x,y,z)$ represents parameters of a physical system that must be positive to make sense (so nonpositive or complex solutions make no sense for my problem).

To solve the system, I first solved $(2)$ for $x$ to get
$$
x=-\frac{y \left(b-a c^2\right)}{2 c-y}.
$$
Substituting this solution for $x$ into $(1)$ and solving the result for $z$ gives
$$
z=\frac{-a c^2+2 a c y-a y^2+b}{y (2 c-y)}.
$$
Substituting these forms of $x$ and $z$ into $(3)$ then gives (after some basic algebraic simplification)
$$
\tag{*}
c = y + ((b - a (c - y)^2) y)/(b - a c^2).
$$
So $(*)$ is a cubic equation in $y$, which has three potential solutions. Once I know which of these solutions is the one I need, I instantly obtain the final solutions for $x$ and $z$ as they are in terms of $y$. **But how do I know which of these solutions is the one I am looking for?**

---

**What I have tried so far:**

I tried having Mathematica solve $(*)$ for me, which gave me three solutions. Call them $y_1$, $y_2$, and $y_3$. Substituting in some possible values for $a$, $b$, and $c$, I found only the $y_1$ solution was positive while the other two were complex.  Does this mean that $y_1$ is the solution I am looking for? My concern is maybe for different $a$, $b$, and $c$ it may be possible that $y_1$ ends up being nonpositive or complex and instead $y_2$ or $y_3$ gives the only positive solution.

To better understand the nature of the roots I computed the polynomial discriminant of $(*)$, which after some simplifications gives
$$
\Delta=\frac{a \left(3 a b c^2+3 \left(b-a c^2\right)^2+29
   b^2\right)}{\left(b-a c^2\right)^3}.
$$
The numerator is never negative so I concluded $\operatorname{sign}(\Delta)=\operatorname{sign}(b-a c^2)$; however, I am unable to make any conclusions about $\operatorname{sign}(b-a c^2)$ as it could be positive or negative. If it were always negative then I would know $y_1$ is the solution I'm looking for as such a result would guarantee(?) that $y_2$ and $y_3$ are a conjugate pair.

So where I'm at right now is for all the values of $a$, $b$, and $c$ that I've tried, $y_1$ is the only solution that makes sense; however, I am not sure if that implies $y_1$ is the correct solution for all possible $a$, $b$, and $c$. Thoughts?

Comment: If you have an expression for $y_1$ as a continuous function of $a, b, c$, it can only stop being positive by either collliding with another root, going off to $+\infty$, or hitting $0$.  Your equation (3) shows that $y$ can't be $0$ when $c > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a tricky problem. The comment by Robert Israel points us in the right direction:

When we plot (3) for $z,x$ constant, we see the following: [image: plot of c=y-y^3z/x for x,z constant]

(Ignore the label on the vertical axis).

Where the vertical lines are different values for $c$ and the curved plot is $y-\frac{z}{x}y^3$. You see that the solutions of this equation are related to the solutions of the equation $$y-\frac{z}{x}y^3=0,$$ which can be solved to give $y=0$ or $y=\pm\sqrt{\frac xz}$. So we have two solutions $y>0$ and one solution $y<0$. Let these three solutions be $y_1<y_2\le y_3$.

In particular, if $c$ is too big, there is only one negative solution and two complex solutions.

We can thus conclude that **If there are two complex solutions, then there are no positive solutions**.

This already is an answer to your question: You should *not* take your $y_1$, but instead one of the other two solutions. This is what Robert Israel meant.

Furthermore, if $\Delta<0$, there is only one solution for $y$, and from this plot we see that it will be $<0$. So we require $\Delta\ge0$ and thus $b-ac^2\ge0$. (In particular, there are *no* solutions of interest to you when $b<ac^2$).

Combining this with (2) and $x>0$ we see that $y>2c$.

Combining this with (3) we get $y>2(y-\frac zxy^3)$ which (because $y>0$) gives $1>2-1\frac zxy^2$ which gives $y>\sqrt\frac x{2z}$.

Furthermore, we have that $y_2\le y_m$ where $y_m$ is the $y$-value where $y-\frac zxy^3$ takes a maximum. By setting the derivative to $0$ we find that $y_m=\sqrt{\frac x{3z}}<\sqrt{\frac x{2z}}$. So in particular, the value $y_2$ does not work either (As it will give $x<0$) so you will need the biggest value of $y$ that solves your equation.